# How to add disabled attribute to an element using Google Closure?

Tags: google-closure, google-closure-library

I am trying to disable an `input` field using Google Closure. Can anyone tell me what is the syntax for doing that operation using Google Closure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any element on google closure can be disabled using setAttribute() function.

```
/**
* @type {Element}
* @private
*/
this.$title_ = null; // call getElementByClass('','') here;
this.$title_.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Here this.$title is an input element.